# I have changed out a ceiling fan with light for just a light

Tags: wiring

There are a black (hot), white (neutral) and bare copper ground wires coming from the ceiling.  In the wall switch there are 3 black wires joined together with a wire nut.  One of those black wires goes into the wall switch and the black wire from the ceiling goes on the other terminal on the wall switch.  A white common is inserted into the back of the wall switch.  Testing with my meter shows no power when testing across the black and white wires at the ceiling but power between the black and ground wires.  Should I cap off the white wire from the ceiling and connect one light wire to black and one to ground coming from the ceiling or do I need to route a ground wire to the wall switch?  Thanks in advance!!![image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please? Also, is the wall switch just a plain old dumb switch, or does it have other functionality, such as "smart switch" stuff, motion sensing, dimming, or a pilot light?

Comment: **Ignore the grounds**. I don't mean you shouldn't use them (they should all be connected together and to the box if the box is metal and to the switch if the box is not metal). But I mean **don't connect the grounds to ANY black or white wires or any switch or light connections except for 'ground' terminals.** Beyond that, need picutres to figure this out. White is (normally) either neutral or a hot wire in a switch loop (which you may have, it is not at all clear.) **NEED PICTURES**.

Comment: @Jim It looks like you created a second account (per your pending edit). Use the Contact Us form at the bottom to request an account merge

Comment: Can you provide a photo looking squarely into the back of the box for the swtich please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

> Should I cap off the white wire from the ceiling and connect one light
> wire to black and one to ground coming from the ceiling or do I need
> to route a ground wire to the wall switch?

No, you should not do this.

> A white common is inserted into the back of the wall switch.

This is hard to visualize. The 1 pole switch should have 3 terminals: hot source, hot switched and then ground (usually with a green screw). So are you saying the white wire is attached to the ground for the switch? If so, this is wrong.

It *seems* like the white neutral in the switch is the common for the circuit and should be tied to the white wire in the ceiling box. IOWs, there should be an extra white hanging around somewhere near that switch box that either goes to the panel (and that white inside the box goes to ceiling) or goes to the ceiling (and that wire inside the box goes to the panel). I would re-examine the switch box and find your missing white wire.

Comment: For future readers: In some cases the last paragraph is correct. In other cases, power from the panel goes to the fixture first, then a switch loop is run down to the switch. If there's a switch loop, there _SHOULD_ be a black mark (tape, marker, paint, something) on the white wire on the switch, but this is often not done or lost. I believe switch loops were outlawed sometime around NEC 2010, but don't quote me on that.